# Create images dynamically using input parameters

Tags: image, image-processing

I'd like to dynamically either create from scratch or update an image using some input parameters to tweak/seed the images. Lets say I have this image - http://cdn.smashingapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/patterns-mix.jpg - and I want to tweak it by making the flower size bigger or changing the color of the flower. I guess updating an existing image will be harder than creating it from group up.

I am not looking for a final solution but any pointers to the right resources will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Processing](http://processing.org/) to generate such images programmatically.

It is a simple programming language and environment, easy to learn and get started. There is available [a collection of free tutorials](http://processing.org/learning/). [Generative Art](http://www.manning.com/pearson/) book by Matt Pearson is a more artistically-inclined introduction.

Comment: Thanks sastanin. I'll go through the Processing tutorials.